How to test information sent in method locally
I am using Spring Boot for this project. I am trying to see if the update method is sending the correct details or not to the database. This update method is a part of the @PutMapping API. When I try to test the API using Postman, I get this error maybe because it is a remote hosted database:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for table TEST_Company

This is the code of update method:
public CompanyResponse update(Long companyId, Company company) {
    CompanyEntity companyEntityToBeUpdated = repository.findById(companyId).orElseThrow();
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setName(company.getName());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setCompanyLogo(company.getCompanyLogo());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setFax(company.getFax());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setSupplierIdentificationType(company.getSupplierIdentificationType());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setTourismTaxRegistrationNo(company.getTourismTaxRegistrationNo());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setBankAccountNo(company.getBankAccountNo());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setBusinessActivityDescription(company.getBusinessActivityDescription());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setContactNo(company.getContactNo());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setStatus(company.getStatus());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setCorrespondenceEmailAddress(company.getCorrespondenceEmailAddress());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setEInvoiceEmailAddress(company.getEInvoiceEmailAddress());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setMsicCode(company.getMsicCode());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setCountry(company.getCountry());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setCity(company.getCity());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setState(company.getState());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setAddressLine1(company.getAddressLine1());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setAddressLine2(company.getAddressLine2());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setAddressLine0(company.getAddressLine0());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setPostalCode(company.getPostalCode());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setDescription(company.getDescription());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setTin(company.getTin());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setSstRegistrationNo(company.getSstRegistrationNo());
    companyEntityToBeUpdated.setRegistrationIdPassportNo(company.getRegistrationIdPassportNo());

    CompanyEntity updatedCompanyEntity = repository.save(companyEntityToBeUpdated);
    return toCompanyResponse(updatedCompanyEntity);
}

The update method is calling this toCompanyResponse:
private CompanyResponse toCompanyResponse(CompanyEntity company) {
    CompanyResponse companyResponse = modelMapper.map(company, CompanyResponse.class);
    ;
    SeedValue statusSeedValue = seedValueRepository.findBySeedCodeAndValueId(Constants.COMPANY_STATUS_SEED_CODE, company.getStatus()).orElse(new SeedValue());
    StatusResponse status = new StatusResponse(statusSeedValue.getValueId(), statusSeedValue.getDisplayValue());
    companyResponse.setStatus(status);

    SeedValue countrySeedValue = seedValueRepository.findBySeedCodeAndValueId(Constants.COMPANY_COUNTRY_SEED_CODE, company.getCountry()).orElse(new SeedValue());
    CountryResponse country = new CountryResponse(countrySeedValue.getValueId(), countrySeedValue.getDisplayValue());
    companyResponse.setCountry(country);

    SeedValue stateSeedValue = seedValueRepository.findBySeedCodeAndValueId(Constants.COMPANY_STATE_SEED_CODE, company.getState()).orElse(new SeedValue());
    StateResponse state = new StateResponse(stateSeedValue.getValueId(), stateSeedValue.getDisplayValue());
    companyResponse.setState(state);

    CityResponse city = new CityResponse(company.getCity(), company.getCity());
    companyResponse.setCity(city);

    SeedValue msicCodeSeedValue = seedValueRepository.findBySeedCodeAndValueId(Constants.COMPANY_MSIC_CODE_SEED_CODE, company.getMsicCode()).orElse(new SeedValue());
    MsicCodeResponse msicCode = new MsicCodeResponse(msicCodeSeedValue.getValueId(), msicCodeSeedValue.getDisplayValue());
    companyResponse.setMsicCode(msicCode);

    return companyResponse;
}

This is the @PutMapping API code:
@PutMapping("{companyId}")
public ResponseEntity<CompanyResponse> update(@PathVariable Long companyId, @RequestBody Company company) {
    CompanyResponse updatedCompany = companyService.update(companyId, company);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedCompany);
}

It looks like everything is correct, but on the website when I try update the information, others are updated except for SstRegistrationNo only is not updated in the database, so I am not sure why. I assume the issue lies in the toCompanyResponse method but still not very sure.
Is there another way for me to test if the information is sent correctly on my local machine or maybe write a unit testing, I don't know much how to do that.

If you are using intellij. use the debug and see the line by line execution. also from the code above i dont see anything wrong. i would suggest doing debug.

Also with respect to your error message it seems to be access issue, so check your data base configuration and also application config if you have any kind of config writen for the postgresql.

is SstRegistrationNo your primary key? Can you also post the entity/schema?

@promitamaitra I have found the cause, yes it is in the entity. I changed the rules of the SstRegistrationNo column in the entity thank you for pointing out

@Irfan Can you please elaborate, I'm curious to know the cause and the possible fix? Thanks.

@SamPaulIsaac Sure, turns out I just completely missed the rules set in the entity. Initially it was set as (updatable = false). I just removed that part and now I'm able to update successfully. The rest of the code is already fine. The issue is I didn't have permission to update remote database so I had to just commit and test it on live production. Thankfully it worked

@Irfan Got it. Thanks for the explanation.
